# How Can I Pass Query String Parameters Without a Query String in JSP?

Tags: jsp

OK, so I have a href link that that contains an ID value as part of a query string. It is in a table column, so the value is new every line.   If I cut the id value off the URl I get a missing servlet parameter error. I have tried turning the link into a form, a hidden field, I've basically tried a number of different things, but the fact is I need to somehow get it to pass over to the next page so that the page will work as it's supposed to without the information displaying in the URL.

Since it's not a form directly, I'm not really sure to go about this and was wondering if someone could please point me in the right direction?

Comment: I am not sure though but it seems that you have lots of link and on click of that link,you go to some other page where you want to access which link you clicked?am i correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I ended up doing it....

I created a form with the action going to the page that I wanted the link to go to. The form is a post form.

The parameter is put into a hidden field. In the example I used below I have an image button, but in other versions i had to use for this task I used a regular input type submit button, and stylized it to look like a hyperlink. If anyone ever needs help with that there are places to look on line.

```
 <form action="editPage" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" id="id1" name="id1" value="${something.somethingId}" />
                    <input type= "image" img src="${contextPath}/img/edit_d1.gif" alt="Paper and pen icon. Edit ${something.somethingId}" title="Edit ${something.somethingId}"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I suspect most web devs already know that a POST form won't put the params in the URL. Glad you discovered it on your own, though.